# Subsetting an address as house number, street, city, state in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have 1 Billion addresses which are kinda in a bad format like:

```
'12-as FS street, 456 DLGG Area, Rand. District, Sydney, Australia 32 1020203'
```

I need the output like

```
Column1:12AS
Column2: FS 456 DLGG Area
Column3: Rand
Column4: Sydney
Column5: Australia
Column6: 32
Column7: 1020203
```

So basically i need them to be separated as `house number, address line, state, country, statecode, pincode` and remove words like `street, district, countryside, road etc`.

Also I need to search for the most frequent words above a particular threshold.

Comment: What is the `FS` in `FS street` and why does it go to _Column2_ and not in _Column1_?

Comment: Also, are they all in Australia? That would be significantly larger than the number of people living there, and I doubt even if all the businesses' addresses were counted in as well, you'd get a number that high for only Australian addresses.

Comment: Does all your data look like this

Comment: the data looks comma-separated. i suggest you start with the python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: I have tried using various regex combinations to first clean the data for -!#$ etc and other special characters via space. Then search for the First alpha numeric with digits in limit of 0-3. I am extracting the last 6 digits directly using regex.

Comment: FS is a street name and maybe a short form of any particular long name and 12-AS forms the house number thats why it is is separate column

Comment: No this a particular example there are cases when data is worse than this with sydney repeating three times and large amount of spelling errors and random characters.

Comment: They are from various countries such as india and europe also ranging from a worst cleaned data format to the most clean data format.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write a parser. Its code would depend on data. Unless somebody has written parser for your specific data format.

List of immediate questions (incomplete):
1) Is comma the separator for all lines?
2) Is comma used inside values (e.g. inside street name)? 
3) List of all words to be removed (road, rd., blvd. etc.)
4) Can address be in the form of "house name" instead of street with number?

This is a random example of address parser with some learning functionality:
https://github.com/datamade/usaddress

If your format and requirements are not exactly matching some existing parser, then you have to write on your own.

Comment: Comma is not a separator for all lines.
Comma is used somewhere inside street name, sometimes before a particular string, its totally used randomly. 
The words to be removed are not defined as it varies from data to data. so my approach to this is to form a DTM and remove the words which are more than a particular threshold frequency. I am not able to figure out though how to make it as a part of loop yet.

Comment: At the same time this a particular example of house address, there are cases when there are random numbers in data which doesnot correspond to address house numbers, sometimes house numbers are numeric and sometimes alphanumeric. I am assuming that house number will be less than pincode.

Comment: It is very risky to remove words just based on frequency. E.g. there could be some popular street name (which could be in many different towns). You can have non-numeric house numbers (14/16, or "Red roses"). If your data is not well structured some machine learning approach (like in the project linked above) would be more appropriate (and it can take into account frequencies, too).

Comment: I truly understand what you are saying, i will be seeing the words based on frequency also. But to reach that level i have to take the data to be cleaned at this level. Also i checked the API you shared its a parser for us only and that too in a particular format that will not help me in dealing will such a messy data. Can i follow any other approach using regex or any packages in python which can help me reach the level in want even if it takes 2-3 steps rather than one?

Comment: If your data are inconsistent, without simple algorithmic structure, then the first step is data analysis, which then would lead to actual technical solution. It can lead to bayesian methods, neural networks, manually crafted algorithm (based on regexp, frequencies, ...), anything else. I cannot help you more without doing actual data analysis work on your actual data.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will build something around this then :)